# In my deno fresh app, I can't get form inputs and send them to an async function

Tags: forms, post, event-handling, deno, freshjs

This is a deno "fresh" framework app and I have a island that allows the admin to create new users. Obviously this is a security vulnerability but this is just a testing proof of concept and I'm just trying to get a "fresh" app to send form data to the backend. This is my `Creator` island.

islands/Creator.tsx

```
// import { useState } from "preact/hooks";
import { useState, useEffect } from "preact/hooks";
import { Handlers, PageProps } from "$fresh/server.ts";
import UserDb from "../database.ts";

interface CreatorProps {
    email: string,
    key: string
}

export default function Creator(props: CreatorProps) {
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const emailInput = event.target.email;
    const ageInput = event.target.key;
    console.log(emailInput.value);
    console.log(ageInput.value);
    createNewUser(emailInput.value, ageInput.value)
  };

  async function createNewUser(email, key) {
    console.log(email);
    console.log(key);
    const headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      });
    const opts = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: email,
          key: key,
        })
      }
    const rawPosts = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/createUser', opts);
    console.log(rawPosts);
  }
    return (
      <div>
        <form onsubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h1 class="text rounded-lg p-4 my-8"> Search </h1>
          <input class="center rounded-lg p-4 my-8" type="text" name="email" />
          <input class="center rounded-lg p-4 my-8" type="text" name="key" />
          <br />
          <button
              class="px-5 py-2.5 text-sm font-medium bg-blue-600 rounded-md shadow disabled:(bg-gray-800 border border-blue-600 opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed)"
              type="submit">Submit
          </button>
        </form>
        <br />
        {/* <ul>
          {results.map((name) => <li key={name}>{name}</li>)}
        </ul> */}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

And when I typed `uiui` and `rrgg` in the email and key fields and hit enter, I got this error in my terminal:

```
Watcher File change detected! Restarting!
Listening on http://localhost:8000/
NOTICE: relation "users" already exists, skipping
Request {
  bodyUsed: false,
  headers: Headers {
  accept: "*/*",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
  connection: "keep-alive",
  "content-length": "29",
  "content-type": "text/plain",
  host: "localhost:8000",
  origin: "http://localhost:8000",
  referer: "http://localhost:8000/create",
  "sec-ch-ua": '"Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"',
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
  "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"macOS"',
  "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
  "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
  "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0...."
},
  method: "POST",
  redirect: "follow",
  url: "http://localhost:8000/api/createUser"
}
Request {
  bodyUsed: false,
  headers: Headers {
  accept: "*/*",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
  connection: "keep-alive",
  "content-length": "29",
  "content-type": "text/plain",
  host: "localhost:8000",
  origin: "http://localhost:8000",
  referer: "http://localhost:8000/create",
  "sec-ch-ua": '"Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"',
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
  "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"macOS"',
  "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
  "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
  "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0...."
},
  method: "POST",
  redirect: "follow",
  url: "http://localhost:8000/api/createUser"
}
Request {
  bodyUsed: false,
  headers: Headers {
  accept: "*/*",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
  connection: "keep-alive",
  "content-length": "29",
  "content-type": "text/plain",
  host: "localhost:8000",
  origin: "http://localhost:8000",
  referer: "http://localhost:8000/create",
  "sec-ch-ua": '"Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"',
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
  "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"macOS"',
  "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
  "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
  "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0...."
},
  method: "POST",
  redirect: "follow",
  url: "http://localhost:8000/api/createUser"
}
Request {
  bodyUsed: false,
  headers: Headers {
  accept: "*/*",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
  connection: "keep-alive",
  "content-length": "29",
  "content-type": "text/plain",
  host: "localhost:8000",
  origin: "http://localhost:8000",
  referer: "http://localhost:8000/create",
  "sec-ch-ua": '"Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"',
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
  "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"macOS"',
  "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
  "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
  "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0...."
},
  method: "POST",
  redirect: "follow",
  url: "http://localhost:8000/api/createUser"
}
Request {
  bodyUsed: false,
  headers: Headers {
  accept: "*/*",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
  connection: "keep-alive",
  "content-length": "29",
  "content-type": "text/plain",
  host: "localhost:8000",
  origin: "http://localhost:8000",
  referer: "http://localhost:8000/create",
  "sec-ch-ua": '"Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"',
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
  "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"macOS"',
  "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
  "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
  "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0...."
},
  method: "POST",
  redirect: "follow",
  url: "http://localhost:8000/api/createUser"
}
```

Notice `email` and `key` aren't even logging on the server side, and the function appears to be running several times

And I got this in my web console:

[image]

So why are `email` and `key` being read and logged just fine in `handleSubmit` but not in `createNewUser()`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an api route.

`/routes/api/createNewUser.ts`

```
import { HandlerContext } from "$fresh/server.ts";

export const handler = async (_req: Request, _ctx: HandlerContext): Response => {
  if(_req.method === 'POST') {
        const body = await _req.json();
        const {email, key} = body;
        
        console.log('email', email);
        console.log('key', key);

        /* your logic to use email & key to create user here */
        
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({
            message: 'User created successfully.'
        }), {
            status: 200,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    }
}
```